# Is NSInMemoryStoreType incompatible with group by fetch request?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I want to use `NSPersistentContainer` with store of type `NSInMemoryStoreType` in unit tests. I have some entities that I want to group by date and I want to write unit test for it.

The code for instantiating in-memory persistent container:

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
storeDescription.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
    print(storeDescription)
    if let loadingError = error {
       print(loadingError.localizedDescription)
    }
 }
```

error I'm getting:

```
caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "Unsupported fetch request: store <NSMemoryObjectStore: 0x6000002c9bc0> (URL: file:///dev/null) does not support GROUP BY"
```

When I use NSPersistentContainer backed by SQLite, everything works fine. Is this possible that in-memory container is not compatible with group by requests? I thought that container with various types are interchangeable.

Comment: [`propertiesToGroupBy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506191-propertiestogroupby): An array of objects that indicates how data should be grouped before a select statement is run **in a SQL database.**

Comment: You're right, I haven't check the documentation in details.

Comment: @MartinR should we write separate code for in-memory stores where in, we code the work done by GROUP BY? But this thing feels a bit wrong to me as we don't want this separate code, just for testing purpose. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @MichalMoskala please let me know if you found workaround.

Comment: @RohanBhale Setup SQL stack in tmp directory instead of in-memory stack

Comment: @MichalMoskala even better, don't use any tmp file, use /dev/null to get de-facto in-memory store with all the features of file backed SQL store

It's not documented well, but they talk about it in the 2018 WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/224/